# What different between this java source code to create object in java?

Tags: java

I am new in java.

Example 1 :

`MyClass mc = new MyClass();`

and

Example 2 :

`MyClass mc = (MyClass)obj;`

Comment: The second example doesn't create an object, it casts an existing one to type `MyClass`.

Comment: `(MyClass)obj;` doesn't create new object, it just cast an existing one.

Comment: **The first one creates** an instance of `MyClass` using the constructor of that class and **the second one casts** an `Object obj` to an instance of `MyClass`, at least it will try to do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one creates a new object. The second one cast obj object to MyClass object.

Answer (score 0):

In first variant you create an object, in second you assign the link from other object with cast to you type of object.